# How do you create a listbox where the user can reorganise the items in it in an asp.net project in visual studio 2017?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, listbox

Basically I want 2 listbox

one with "requests" and one in a "playlist"

I want to be able to accept a request in the playlist

When the element is in the playlist, I want the user to be able to reorganise the songs in the "playlist" using only the mouse and drag and drop.

I am still new to asp.net and don't get how I "connect" my c# code to the html in the webform.

Comment: I would guess you're new to web development in general.  Sorting a list via drag-and-drop on a web page is an HTML/Javascript question.  But once you've got it sorted, presumably you'll want to let the server know there's been a change; so you'll need to submit your changes to the server as well.

Comment: Yes, I already programmed a few local applications, but I am a bit confused right now. I should have put javascript in the tags I guess.

Comment: What do you mean by "local applications"?  pure-html web pages?  Desktop applications?

Comment: Desktop application. Sorry, my first language is not English.

Comment: That's the kind of mistake native-speakers would make.  The best advice I can give is to break your question down to a few very specific questions.  I don't recommend doing that *here* - but it's a good exercise).  Build as clear a project specification as you can, and break that down into smaller pieces.  Doing that will give you insights to what you're *really* needing to know.